# tabindex in achor tag, sinking the image size

Tags: html, css, logging

```
<a id="advertiser_modal" class="min-button in-block" tabindex="-1"> 
 <img width="9" height="10" src="/themes/default/css/images/new-window-icon.png"> Select an Advertiser
</a>
```

In the above html code i have img wrapped inside anchor tag, having tabindex, when i click on the new-window-icon.png, the image is sinking in size,

But when i tried removing the tabindex,

```
<a id="advertiser_modal" class="min-button in-block"> <!--tabindex="-1"-->
  <img width="9" height="10" src="/themes/default/css/images/new-window-icon.png"> Select an Advertiser
</a>
```

Now when i click on image new-window-icon.png, it is not sinking, working properly,
But i want that tabindex to be there,

Any suggestions please,

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u Create a jsfiddle.net link  or upload to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `outline:none !important`

```
.min-button{outline: none !important; }​
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/jQLd4/

Thanks for your reply, just it could not solve my issue, when i click on the image, same thing is happening, i mean, image is sinking.

CSS used

```
.min-button {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none !important;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none !important;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none !important;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #EF8C41 0%, #D97726 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-color: #DE8038 #DE8038 #A3563C !important;
    border-image: none !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-width: 1px !important;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```